# Sort a class of object's attribute in vector by highest occurrence(same alphabet)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, operator-overloading

Question-  List the passengers sorted by highest number of bookings.

```
  void defaultvalue(vector<indi>&a)
    {
        a.push_back(indi("Kobe","17-05-2015","KUL","SIN"));
        a.push_back(indi("Kobe","14-04-2015","KUL","HKG"));
        a.push_back(indi("David","08-04-2015","JED","HKG"));
```

how can i implement the count and sort part..by using algorithm..
and show Kobe 1st and follow by david depends on number of booking ...
please any 1 can help me..

Comment: Your code sample is incorrect (does not compile) and your question is far from clear.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), you can specify a compare function (or functor) to std::sort.
Therefore, you can write up a function that does compare two "pas" objects in the way you want.

Comment: can u give me a simple example.. haha.. im beginner for this subject..please please TT